# Get fun instead of have fun

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct to say *get fun* 'get pleasure, receive positive emotions' instead of *have fun*?

Answer (score 2):

Grammatically, it is perfectly fine: a verb with a noun phrase as its object.

As far as I know, no native English speaker would say it.

But it is the sort of expression which can arise unpredictably and take off. It could be how young people speak next year, or in five years' time, for all we know.